# Guild experience math

Tags: world-of-warcraft

What are the formulas to calculate the levels and the experience gain of a Guild?

- Meaning is how much XP the guild earns when completing a quest a % of what that quest gives you or is it a flat rate.
- How much do you earn per kill...
- etc.

Full answers are appreciated I am working on a calculator. Thank you for your time and responses.

Answer (score 3):

#### How guild experience works

There are many methods of gaining guild experience;

- Raiding in a guild group
- Dungeons in a guild group
- Arena in a guild group
- Completing quests that give experience
- Completing daily quests
- Completing guild challenges

Experience in raid and dungeon groups is granted provided you meet the requirement for the number of people in the party. For example, with dungeons you will get get scaling experience based on the number of people from the guild that are in the party as follows;

```
3 guild members                50%
4 guild members                100%
5 guild members                125%
```

For raids, the number of people required in the group from the guild is a set threshold, and simply exceeding this threshold will provide the bonus;

```
25 man raiding                 20 guild members required
10 man raiding                 8 guild members required
Pre-WotLK 25/40 man raids      10 guild members required
```

For arena, the whole arena group must consist of members of the guild to qualify for guild experience.

Completing quests will provide experience to your guild for each quest completed, the amount of guild experience gained is approximately 60k experience per quest handed in since the release of Mists of Pandaria. This means that you can get a guild to level 25 by completing around 14100 quests.

#### Guild experience required for each level

```
level    reputation needed     daily quests needed 
1        N/A                   N/A
2        16,580,000            277
3        18,240,000            288
4        19,900,000            332
5        21,550,000            360
6        32,220,000            387
7        24,880,000            415
8        26,530,000            443
9        28,190,000            470
10       29,850,000            498
11       31,510,000            526
12       33,170,000            553
13       34,820,000            581
14       36,490,000            609
15       38,140,000            636
16       39,800,000            664
17       41,450,000            691
18       43,120,000            719
19       44,780,000            750
20       46,430,000            774
21       48,090,000            802
22       49,750,000            830
23       51,410,000            857
24       53,060,000            885
25       54,730,000            913
```

As there is no cap on experience gain anymore, there is no "minimum" amount of time that it takes to level a guild to level 25 as there was at the start of Cataclysm.

<sup>[Source on WoWpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org/Guild_advancement)</sup>